# Depending on values inside a Two Dimensional array convert another single array into binary in C

Tags: c, arrays

Previously I made a code wherein i was converting values inside a one dimensional array into binary.

```
int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
int my_data[10] = {0};
int index1 = 0;

void main()     {

    my_data[0] = 1;
    my_data[1] = 3;
    my_data[2] = 9;
    my_data[3] = 10;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(int);i++)
    {

         if(my_data[i] > 0){

         index1 = my_data[i];

         myDataBinary[index1] = 1;

        //printf("my data %d = %d\n",index1,myDataBinary[index1]);

     }

  }

}
```

Now how can I pass values inside a Two dimensional array `Array[j][i]` to the above binary conversion function so that at the output I again get only a single `myDataBinary[]` array. Any kind of help would be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get the question. Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you have in your two-dimensional array?

Comment: I don't see a function in that code.

Comment: in the above code I have my_data[], which is one dimensional. SImilarly if i Have it as two dimensional. i want to use the for loop in the bove code as function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean this? Two nested loops?

```
int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
// Not sure if this syntax is allowed, but you get the point
int my_data[10][10] = { {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} };
int index1 = 0;

void main()
{
    my_data[0][3] = 1;
    my_data[1][2] = 3;
    my_data[2][8] = 9;
    my_data[3][0] = 10;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(maydata[0]);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; i<sizeof(my_data[0])/sizeof(int);i++)
        {
            if(my_data[i][j] > 0)
            {
                index1 = my_data[i][j];
                myDataBinary[index1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```